# How to find difference between 2 timestamps in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, time, timestamp

I'm having this data frame and here I want to find out time difference for each row

```
      open     close
0   09:44:00  10:07:00
1   10:07:00  11:01:00
2   11:05:00  13:05:00
```

I tried the following code.

```
import numpy as np
(df['open']-df['close'])/np.timedelta64(1,'m')
```

But the below error occurred

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the values with `pd.to_datetime()` before the substract:

```
print(
    (pd.to_datetime(df['close']) - pd.to_datetime(df['open'])) / np.timedelta64(1,'m')
)
```

Prints:

```
0     23.0
1     54.0
2    120.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but the problem persists `https://colab.research.google.com/drive/126NV4zJvkMyMcG9IFd4aI9MfUjrfNERn?usp=sharing`. Please see me notebook

Comment: @SamarPratapSingh remove the `.dt.time` part. The columns need to be of type datetime to work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use this function.

```
pd.Timedelta(df['open']-df['close']).seconds
```

The result is in seconds

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but the problem persists `https://colab.research.google.com/drive/126NV4zJvkMyMcG9IFd4aI9MfUjrfNERn?usp=sharing`. Please see me notebook